# Determine correlation and independence when only the joint density is given?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The joint pdf of $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is:

$$f_{X}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{cases} Ar^2,&0 \le r \le R\\[0.2cm]  0,& \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

where $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}$ and $A,R$ are constants.

(1) I would like to know if they're uncorrelated. One way is to determine if $$E[(X-E[X])^T(X-E[X])] = diag(Var(x_1),...,Var(x_n))$$

So for element $X_i,X_j$ I have
$$Cov(X_i,X_j) = E[X_iX_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]$$

But $E[X_i] = \int_0^R x_i f_{x_i}(\cdot) dx_i$ and I am not sure how to determine the marginal density of $X_i$ form the joint. If I assume they're iid (may not be justified) the I have
$$f_{x_i} = f_{x_n} = A \int_0^{\sqrt{R}} dx_1 \int_0^{\sqrt{R} - x_1} dx_2 \ldots \int_0^{\sqrt{R} - x_1 - \ldots x_{n-1}} dx_{n-1} \cdot (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_{n}^2)$$

But this brute force approach looks unreasonable and I am wondering if there's another way? Assuming the steps thus far have been correct.

(2) Without knowing the marginal distribution, how would I determine if the $X_i$'s are independent?

Comment: Yup, Sorry I was asking so many questions on this site that I lost track of all of them! Thanks for all your help on this one and the others that you commented on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $i$, the density $f_X(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is an even function of $x_i$ hence, for every $i\ne j$, $(-X_i,X_j)$ is distributed like $(X_i,X_j)$, in particular, $E(-X_i)=E(X_i)$ and $E(-X_iX_j)=E(X_iX_j)$.

Thus, $E(X_i)=E(X_iX_j)=0$, which is enough to conclude that $E(X)=0$ and that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$ is diagonal.

To go further, note that the density $f$ of the distribution of $\|X\|$ is proportional to the function $r\mapsto r^2\cdot r^{n-1}=r^{n+1}$ on $(0,R)$, that is, $f(r)=(n+2)r^{n+1}R^{-n-2}$ on $(0,R)$. Thus, $E(\|X\|^2)=\int_0^Rr^2f(r)\,\mathrm dr=\frac{n+2}{n+4}R^2$. By symmetry, $E(X_i^2)=\frac1nE(\|X\|^2)=\frac{n+2}{n(n+4)}R^2$ for every $i$, hence, finally, $\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)=\frac{n+2}{n(n+4)}R^2I_n$.

Comment: May I ask how you went from $E(-X_iX_j) = E(X_i X_j)$ to: "Thus, $E(X_i) = E(X_i X_j)$"?

Comment: ?? I did not go from this to what you wrote, but to $E(X_i)=0$ and $E(X_iX_j)=0$.

Comment: Yup you're right I didn't read carefully. Could you argue the x's are not independent using symmetry of density? or equivalent some other characteristic other than computing the integral and see?

Comment: No, symmetry of density cannot disprove independence. The fastest way to disprove independence would be to note that the support of the density is not a product.

Comment: By "support of the density is not a product", do you mean $f_{X}$ relates the variables by an expression that cannot be factored into a product over each variable? Would this be sufficient proof over checking the conditions: $\Pr(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \Pr(x_1)\times\ldots\times\Pr(x_n)$, or equivalently $\Pr(x_1) = \Pr(x_1|x_2,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: By "the support of the density is not a product", I mean that the support of the density is not a product. Recall that the support of some measure $\mu$ is the set of points $x$ such that $\mu(B(x,t))\gt0$ for every $t\gt0$.

Comment: So just to be clear you're saying if $f_{X} = X_1^2 \times \ldots \times X_n^2$ then it's immediately clear that the $X$'s are independent. My primary issue is that whether this constitutes to a sufficient proof, relative to the alternative proof where the condition $\Pr(x_1) = \Pr(x_1|x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is checked for all possible values of $X$'s, which would only be possible for discrete variables that take on a small set of values.

Comment: Adding to the comment above,if the density is a sum over variables $X_j$'s, and the sum is not bounded, then are the $X_j$'s independent?

Comment: You seem to be willing to make the comments drift to different, albeit related, questions. Please don't. If you have other problems, post other questions.

Comment: ok I posted a new question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070991/check-for-independence-of-variables-when-the-density-or-distribution-is-known. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Interesting downvote--purely for mathematical reasons, to be sure.

Comment: if I down-voted you it was probably by accident.